# Import Math doesn't work in either PyCharm or Spyder

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, anaconda, spyder

Just started learning Python.
Wrote this following code in PyCharm as well as Spyder, but it doesn't show the output.

[image]

[image]

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: If not ran in a REPL, you need a `print()` statement

Comment: Hey Simba, To get know more about Interactive Shell vs Script, please check out this youtube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_UU3G298f08.

Comment: @DillonDavis what will be the correct syntax?

Comment: @Simba `print(expression)`. In this specific case: `print(math.sqrt(16))`

Comment: Please don't post images of code/data/Tracebacks.  Just copy the text, paste it in your question and format it as code.
[You should not post code as an image because:](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2823755)

Comment: @wwii Ok... Won't do it again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you ran "match.sqrt(16)", you are running the command, but not printing it so you can see the result. Try this:

```
import math
print(math.sqrt(16))
```